# Prove $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-2}=\frac{-1}{4}$ using $\epsilon-\delta $ condition

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt was to prove $\lim_{x \to 2}\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-2}=\frac{-1}{4}$ using $\epsilon-\delta $ definition, I got the inequality $$|x-2|<4 \epsilon |x|,~\text{for}~x \neq 2,$$ to make $$|\frac{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-2}+\frac{1}{4}|=\frac{|x-2|}{4|x|}<\epsilon.$$
How to proceed by taking a suitable $\delta$ so that above inequality holds for $|x-2|<\delta$.

Comment: Try using the triangle inequality to write a bound for $|x|$ in terms of $|x - 2|$

Comment: $$\frac{\frac1x-\frac12}{x-2}=\frac{2-x}{2x(x-2)}=-\frac{1}{2x}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have deduced, you can easily check that:

$ \displaystyle\left|\frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}}{x-2}+\frac{1}{4}\right|<\epsilon\Leftrightarrow -\epsilon-\frac{1}{4}<-\frac{1}{2x}<\epsilon-\frac{1}{4}\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{2\epsilon+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}<x<\frac{1}{-2\epsilon+\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}}\Leftrightarrow \frac{2}{4\epsilon+1}<x<\frac{2}{-4\epsilon+1}$

So, you now have that: $\delta \leq \min{\displaystyle \{\frac{2}{-4\epsilon+1},\frac{2}{4\epsilon+1}\}}$.  Since $\epsilon>0,$ set $\delta \displaystyle\leq \frac{2}{-4\epsilon+1}$.

But because we want $\delta > 0$, we must have

$\displaystyle\frac{2}{-4\epsilon+1}>0\Leftrightarrow \epsilon <\frac{1}{4}$

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, if $\epsilon = 10$, you get that $\delta$ should be a negative number.

Comment: I think that you could get a restriction on $\epsilon$, like set $\frac{2}{-4\epsilon+1}>0$. Obvsiouly, we usually take $\epsilon$ to be arbitrarily small.

Comment: There is a step in this where reciprocals are taken. The order of the inequality symbols needs to be treated carefully at that step. This appears to use $-A<-B \iff\frac{1}{A}<\frac{1}{B}$ and that's not how it works if the signs of $A,B$ are different in the first place.

Comment: @alex.jordan Sorry, about that. Feel free to edit it. I am pretty time-pressured right now and I did it quickly in my mind.

Comment: I am just offering an explanation for @mathcounterexamples.net's observation about $\epsilon=10$. If $\epsilon<\frac14$ in the first place, it's not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\delta = \min (1, 4 \epsilon)$. Then for $\vert x-2\vert \lt \delta$, you have (using reverse triangle inequality)

$$2 - \vert x \vert\lt \vert x -2\vert \le 1$$ and therefore $\vert x \vert \gt 1$. Which leads to

$$\frac{\vert x-2 \vert}{4\vert x \vert} \le \frac{\vert x-2 \vert}{4} \lt \frac{\delta}{4} \le \epsilon $$